# Qt Widgets disappear when using spacer or addStretch function

Tags: qt, widget, qt5

I am using a class taken from an Qt example to insert status lights to my GUI. The class looks like:

```
class LightWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool on READ isOn WRITE setOn)
public:
    LightWidget(const QColor &color, QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QWidget(parent), m_color(color), m_on(false) {}

    bool isOn() const
        { return m_on; }
    void setOn(bool on)
    {
        if (on == m_on)
            return;
        m_on = on;
        update();
    }

public slots:
    void turnOff() { setOn(false); }
    void turnOn() { setOn(true); }

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override
    {
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
        if (!m_on){
            painter.setBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0, 127));
        }else{
            painter.setBrush(m_color);
            //painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, width(), height());

        }
        painter.drawEllipse(0, 3,9, 9);
    }

private:
    QColor m_color;
    bool m_on;
};
```

In general I tried two different things.
First, in the MainWindow I create two instances of the `LightWidget` Widget and set the `parent` to the widget, which represents a single page of a `QTabWidget`. In the parent widget I gave a QHBoxLayout where the two new widget along with a label will be added.

```
m_red = new LightWidget(Qt::red,ui->tabWidget);
m_green = new LightWidget(Qt::green,ui->tabWidget);
m_red->setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
m_green->setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);

QLabel *label = new QLabel("Status:");
ui->statusLayout->addWidget(label);
ui->statusLayout->addWidget(m_red);
ui->statusLayout->addWidget(m_green);
ui->statusLayout->addStretch(); //This does not work!
```

As a result, all three elements are spread over the entire width. But when I use the `addStretch()` Method, only the label is visible and the other two widgets are gone.

In a second try I wrapped the to two widget into a single on, which looks like:

```
myWidget = new QWidget(ui->tabWidget);
m_red = new LightWidget(Qt::red,ui->deviceModeLoop);
m_green = new LightWidget(Qt::green,ui->deviceModeLoop);
m_red->setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
m_green->setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);

myLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
myLayout->addWidget(m_red);
myLayout->addWidget(m_green);

myWidget->setContentsMargins(QMargins());
myWidget->setLayout(myLayout);

QLabel *label = new QLabel("Status:");
ui->statusLayout->addWidget(label);
ui->statusLayout->addWidget(myWidget);
```

Whille the label is still visible, the two other widgets are not. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think your light widgets are becoming zero sized because they do not advertise what size they prefer to be. `addStretch` is going to take all space not reserved by widgets. `QLabel` overrides `sizeHint()` and `minimumSizeHint()` to advertise to the layout how much space it needs. Your widgets do not override those methods and by default an invalid QSize is returned by those methods which is probably interpreted as zero sized.

Answer (score 0):

I think your light widgets are becoming zero sized because they do not advertise what size they prefer to be. `addStretch` is going to take all space not reserved by widgets. `QLabel` overrides `sizeHint()` and `minimumSizeHint()` to advertise to the layout how much space it needs.
Your widgets do not override those methods and by default an invalid QSize is returned by those methods, which is probably interpreted as zero sized.